# How to grant read access to only some resources in an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

Lets say I have a user "User A" and someone with more privilege "Owner 1". "Owner 1", in Subscription "Product" makes 2 different resource groups, one for Dev resources, and one for Test resources. "Owner 1" has the Owner role on the Subscription "Product".

How do give "User A" reader permissions for everything inside the Dev resource group, but not give away the existence of the Test resource group? Giving "User A" reader permissions on the whole Subscription "Product" won't work because they would be able to see the Test resource group. In our tests, giving "User A" reader permissions on the Dev resource group is not totally sufficient as they are not able to see the resource group at all from the "Resource Groups" view.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In our tests, giving "User A" reader permissions on the Dev resource group is not totally sufficient as they are not able to see the resource group at all from the "Resource Groups" view.

Well, actually it is sufficient for User A to access the Dev resource group, you just need to search for the group name like below, click it, you will find you are able to access the resources in the group.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That really helps. If you went to the home screen, and clicked "Resource Groups" it does not appear there for you, does it?

Comment: @B.Witter Yes, the first time it will not, but it will appear there after refreshing the portal at the second time, it maybe a bug.